# jq error cannot iterate over null but need to make a different choice

Tags: jq

I have a jq filter that selects the rows I need. But sometimes these lines can be empty, and then everything breaks and the rule does not work. I tried to use the if-then-else construct but to no avail.

A rule that works if you process the following json:

`.metadata.namespace as $ns | (.spec.rules[0].match.any[].resources.kinds[] / "/") | [select(.[1])[0] // null, select(.[2])[1] // null, last] as [$version,$group,$kind] | {namespace: $ns, kind: $kind, group: $version, version: $group} | with_entries(select(.value!=null))`

suitable json:

```json
{
  "apiVersion": "kyverno.io/v1",
  "kind": "posdfsdf",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "e-eion",
    "namespace": "kke",
    "annotations": {
      "policies.kyverno.io/title": "Dation",
      "policies.kyverno.io/category": "Pod Security Standards (Restricted)",
      "policies.kyverno.io/severity": "medium",
      "policies.kyverno.io/subject": "Pod",
      "kyverno.io/kyverno-version": "1.6.0",
      "kyverno.io/kubernetes-version": "1.22-1.23",
      "policies.kyverno.io/description": "se`.      "
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "validationFailureAction": "audit",
    "background": true,
    "rules": [
      {
        "name": "tion",
        "match": {
          "any": [
            {
              "resources": {
                "kinds": [
                  "Pod"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "validate": {
          "message": "Prisd",
          "pattern": {
            "spec": {
              "=(eners)": [
                {
                  "secxt": {
                    "altion": "false"
                  }
                }
              ],
              "=(i)": [
                {
                  "sext": {
                    "alcalation": "false"
                  }
                }
              ],
              "containers": [
                {
                  "setext": {
                    "an": "false"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

example on which the rule stops working:

```json
{
  "apiVersion": "k/v1",
  "kind": "Picy",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "denylation",
    "namespace": "what",
  },
  "spec": {
    "validationFailureAction": "audit",
    "background": true,
    "rules": [
      {
        "name": "deny-privilege-escalation",
        "match": {
          "resources": {
            "kinds": [
              "Pod"
            ]
          }
        },
        "validate": {
          "message": "Priviles[*].securityContext.allowPrind spec.initContalse`.",
          "pattern": {
            "spec": {
              "=(iners)": [
                {
                  "=(seext)": {
                    "=(aln)": "false"
                  }
                }
              ],
              "containers": [
                {
                  "=(stext)": {
                    "=(al)": "false"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

how can this be fixed? I need the rule to work out in any cases and give output

Comment: The first json doesn't work with the filter.

Comment: demo https://jqplay.org/s/JE0KaJ2F9A

Comment: Can you paste the expected output for the second json ?

Comment: @Philippe the same {
  "namespace": "what",
  "kind": "Pod"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
.metadata.namespace as $ns |
((.spec.rules[0].match | .. | (objects | .resources.kinds[]?)) / "/") |
[select(.[1])[0] // null, select(.[2])[1] // null, last] as [$version,$group,$kind] |
{namespace: $ns, kind: $kind, group: $version, version: $group} |
with_entries(select(.value!=null))
```

Answer (score 0):

The failing json gives the following error:

> parse error: Expected another key-value pair at line 7, column 3

This is caused by the trailing comma found here:

```json
"metadata": {
    "name": "denylation",
    "namespace": "what",
},
```

---

Removing that comma, the following error is thrown:

> jq: error (at :44): Cannot iterate over null (null)

This is caused by the missing `any` key inside the `match` object.

We can 'catch' that error using a `?` ([docs](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#.%5B%5D?)):

```
(.spec.rules[0].match.any[]?.resources.kinds[] / "/") 
                           ^
```

But due to the missing key, the filter does not find anything and the output is empty.

---

###### [Updated jqPlay](https://jqplay.org/s/c7iD0kWlqw)

Comment: it does not give any output

Comment: Yes, as stated in my answer, your filter expects the `any` key to be there, since it's not, the rest of the filter does not produce any ouput.

Comment: ok, but I need the rest of it to be output too.